# Why does a reference in the JVM not take two stack slots

Tags: java, jvm

Looking at the JVM 15 specification ([first two sections here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)), I see that

- `reference`, `int`, and `float` take only one local variable slot and one stack slot
- `long` and `double`, take 2 slots

Everything in the spec points suggests a slot is 32-bits wide. If this is the case, **how can a `reference` work when the JVM heap is very large? Isn't 32-bits just not enough to address potentially massive heaps?** Even if the minimum size of a JVM object 16 bytes, 32-bits would run out of references around a ~70GB heap.

---

#### What I've <s>"tried"</s> checked

Just to check that above is still true on my locally installed 64-bit Java, here's a sample Java class, compiled with `javac -target 8 me/alec/Tester.java`

```java
package me.alec;

public final class Tester {
  public void intArgMethod(int intArg) { }
  public void longArgMethod(long longArg) { }
  public void referenceArgMethod(Tester referenceArg) { }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the output from `javap -v me.alec.Tester`. Note that a the `referenceArgMethod` local size is the same as `referenceIntMethod` and less than `referenceLongMethod` (the extra +1 for all methods is due to the `this` reference argument).

```
  public void intArgMethod(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0

  public void longArgMethod(long);
    descriptor: (J)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0

  public void referenceArgMethod(me.alec.Tester);
    descriptor: (Lme/alec/Tester;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
```